# Implementing Health Check for resource in deployment manager templates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Using Deployment Manager I am trying to deploy compute instance resource running a particular web server which comes up after 5-10 min after booting up and I want deployment manager to check if the web service has come up before giving the status as "SUCCESS",

Is there a way in deployment manager template through which I can implement this check ( a simple get request on server url port 80/443 )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/waiter) through which deployment manager will wait before a stage is passed before giving a success signal.

With this my requirement is fulfilled.